# Multiple Joins With A Count

Tags: mysql

I have several tables like this

A posts table

```
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_by | bigint          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title      | text            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post       | longtext        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

A comments table

```
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comment    | longtext        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post_id    | bigint          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_by | bigint          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

A users table and more

I want to select posts and users and also get the comment count for each post. How can I implement this in one SQL query?

I tried the following query by trying to pass the `comment_count` as a virtual column. But it is failing.

How can I fix this? Thanks

```
SELECT     `post_meta`.`category_id`,
           `post_status`.`status_id`    AS `status_code`,
           `status_codes`.`status_name` AS `status_name`,
           `status_codes`.`color`       AS `status_color`,
           `categories`.`NAME`          AS `category_name`,
           `categories`.`slug`          AS `category_slug`,
           `categories`.`color`         AS `category_color`,
           `posts`.`title`              AS `post_title`,
           `posts`.`created_at`         AS `post_date`,
           `posts`.`id`                 AS `post_id`,
           `0`                          AS `comment_count`,
           `users`.`NAME`               AS `user_name`,
           `users`.`id`                 AS `user_id`
FROM       `posts`
INNER JOIN `post_meta`
ON         `posts`.`id` = `post_meta`.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN  `post_status`
ON         `posts`.`id` = `post_status`.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN  `status_codes`
ON         `post_status`.`status_id` = `status_codes`.`id`
INNER JOIN `categories`
ON         `post_meta`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
INNER JOIN `users`
ON         `users`.`id` = `posts`.`created_by` limit 50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this as a giant `group by` query, but in this case it's easier to just use a correlated subquery

> I strongly recommend you use aliases, as shown

```
SELECT     pm.`category_id`,
           ps.`status_id`   AS `status_code`,
           sc.`status_name` AS `status_name`,
           sc.`color`       AS `status_color`,
           cat.`NAME`       AS `category_name`,
           cat.`slug`       AS `category_slug`,
           cat.`color`      AS `category_color`,
           p.`title`        AS `post_title`,
           p.`created_at`   AS `post_date`,
           p.`id`           AS `post_id`,
           (
             SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM `comments` AS c
             WHERE c.`post_id` = p.`id`
           )                AS `comment_count`,
           u.`NAME`         AS `user_name`,
           u.`id`           AS `user_id`
FROM       `posts` AS p
INNER JOIN `post_meta` AS pm
ON         p.`id` = pm.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN  `post_status` AS ps
ON         p.`id` = ps.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN  `status_codes` AS sc
ON         ps.`status_id` = sc.`id`
INNER JOIN `categories` AS cat
ON         pm.`category_id` = cat.`id`
INNER JOIN `users` AS u
ON         u.`id` = p.`created_by`
limit 50
```

You can also pre-group it, and then do a normal join

```
SELECT     pm.`category_id`,
           ps.`status_id`   AS `status_code`,
           sc.`status_name` AS `status_name`,
           sc.`color`       AS `status_color`,
           cat.`NAME`       AS `category_name`,
           cat.`slug`       AS `category_slug`,
           cat.`color`      AS `category_color`,
           p.`title`        AS `post_title`,
           p.`created_at`   AS `post_date`,
           p.`id`           AS `post_id`,
           c.`comment_count`,
           u.`NAME`         AS `user_name`,
           u.`id`           AS `user_id`
FROM       `posts` AS p
INNER JOIN `post_meta` AS pm
ON         p.`id` = pm.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN  `post_status` AS ps
ON         p.`id` = ps.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN  `status_codes` AS sc
ON         ps.`status_id` = sc.`id`
INNER JOIN `categories` AS cat
ON         pm.`category_id` = cat.`id`
INNER JOIN `users` AS u
ON         u.`id` = p.`created_by`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT c.`post_id`,
           COUNT(*) AS `comment_count`
    FROM `comments` AS c
    GROUP BY
           c.`post_id`
) c
ON         c.`post_id` = p.`id`
limit 50
```

Comment: Thank you this was a life saver